# Google Maps - TransactionTooLargeException

Tags: java, android, google-maps

I am launching Google maps using an normal intent and start an overlay button service to get back to my app.

```
Intent iconServiceIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, FloatingMapIconService.class);
final String mapsUri = "com.google.android.apps.maps";
// lastRequestedAddress is e.g. "Berlin"
Uri intentUri = Uri.parse(String.format("google.navigation:q=%s&mode=b", lastRequestedAddress)); 
Intent mapIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, intentUri);
mapIntent.setPackage(mapsUri);

if (mapIntent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null) {
    startActivity(mapIntent);
    startService(iconServiceIntent);
}
```

When clicking the overlay button:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(FloatingMapIconService.this, MainActivity.class);
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
FloatingMapIconService.this.startActivity(intent);
//stopping the service
FloatingMapIconService.this.stopSelf();
```

Google Maps crashes with the following exception:

```
Process: com.google.android.apps.maps, PID: 4586
    java.lang.RuntimeException: tname=main - android.os.TransactionTooLargeException: data parcel size 2832148 bytes
    at android.app.ActivityThread$StopInfo.run(ActivityThread.java:4209)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6776)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1496)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1386)
Caused by: android.os.TransactionTooLargeException: data parcel size 2832148 bytes
    at android.os.BinderProxy.transactNative(Native Method)
    at android.os.BinderProxy.transact(Binder.java:628)
    at android.app.ActivityManagerProxy.activityStopped(ActivityManagerNative.java:4183)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$StopInfo.run(ActivityThread.java:4201)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751) 
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95) 
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6776) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1496) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1386)
```

I don't know what I am doing wrong, so that maps crashes? I there any problem with the `Intent` flags in my `FloatingMapIconSerivce` class? I would like to clear the stack, so if the user pushes the back button, he should return to maps or return to the home screen and not to the previous `MainActivity` in the 
 task stack.

Comment: Can u share ur service?

Comment: @keshav I copied the service to gist: https://gist.github.com/MreiNerd/0c6cd073ab1f97476d651f3efe5d5681

Answer (score 0):

TransactionTooLargeException occurs when you are trying to pass a large bundle in the intent. Below N devices, the exception was handled below android N but devices with android version N and above, the exception is not handled.

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/TransactionTooLargeException.html

Google recommends to keep all transaction very small. Check the size of the intent and bundle data when starting the activity.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I am not transferring any data back to my app. The call from my app > to maps is working fine, but the intent from maps > to my app, eventually crashes google maps. I am testing on a Samsung Galaxy A5 (2016) running Android 7.0